# How can I test input lag for my keyboard controller Super Smash Bros Melee dolphin?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee, dolphin-emulator

I am fairly new to the Melee scene, even more so to Dolphin.

My question is, using a keyboard controller, is there anything I can do to test the input lag? If there is any input lag, how can I reduce it?